# When I am using rollover in elasticsearch do I write to the alias or to an index?

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have an index `logs-api-00001` and I want to use rollover, so I setup an alias `logs-api`. Do I now send puts to `PUT /logs-api`? Or do I keep sending logs to: `PUT /logs-api-00001`?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a [Rollover index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/indices-rollover-index.html) which you should use.